# How to catch application errors in java/jax-rs

Tags: java, angularjs, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I wonder if there is anything like Application_Error from Global.asax in asp.net but in java?

I am using jersey & angularJS. I already implemented the ServletContextListener that I tested and it works, but cannot find something like application_error

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Starting");
    }

}
```

I also have a class which implements the method filter from ContainerRequestFilter where I validate my jwt token and accept or reject the authorization.

All my methods don't handle the exception within, it means that I want to catch the exception of the whole application even if it is produced in a resource, a method from service layer or data access layer, etc. and try to send an email to admin and redirect to error.html page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some solutions independent of `Jersey` that you can implement for catching all exceptions in a java web application. I am assuming that your project has `web.xml` -

1) **Using Filter** - You can add one `filter` in your web application and catch all exceptions there. `Filter` is like an interceptor which can be called before processing any request.

You can define filter in `web.xml` -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>exceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.MyExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>exceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Now define `MyExceptionFilter` class -

```
public final class MyExceptionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        try {
            // forward request to subsequent filter/resource/servlet
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch ( Throwable ex ) {
            // do whatever you want in case any exception occurred and not caught in the request processing class
            // forward request to error page
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/ErrorPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Problem with this approach is that it is possible to define multiple filters in a web application. The sequence of how these filters will get called is not fixed.

2) **Error Page** - You can also define error page for the web application. In `web.xml`, add below lines -

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/ExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

and then define `ExceptionHandler` servlet -

```
@WebServlet("/ExceptionHandler")
public class ExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processException(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processException(request, response);
    }
    private void processException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        // do whatever you want to do with exception        
        // forward request to error page
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/ErrorPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```